# Postgres use two column in the ON CONFLICT would occur error

Tags: postgresql

I use the query string:

```sql
INSERT INTO public.owner (name, address, public_key) 
VALUES 
('name1', 'address4', 'publicKey1'),
('name1', 'address5', 'publicKey2'),
('name1', 'address6', 'publicKey3')

ON CONFLICT (address, public_key) DO NOTHING;
```

And I got an error message:

```
ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
SQL state: 42P10
```

I knew the answer from the other question similar like mine is adding `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` in the table of column, but I had done that, and the error still here.

My create script is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.owner
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('owner_id_seq'::regclass),
    name character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    address character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    public_key character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    CONSTRAINT "PK_8e86b6b9f94aece7d12d465dc0c" PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT "UQ_5e67355720891990b30c3079806" UNIQUE (address),
    CONSTRAINT "UQ_dbff2cddd177bff09af6381696d" UNIQUE (public_key)
)
```

`CONSTRAINT "UQ_5e67355720891990b30c3079806" UNIQUE (address)` and `"UQ_dbff2cddd177bff09af6381696d" UNIQUE (public_key)` have created in the table.

But the query string still doesn't work.

Is there any mistake I haven't fix?

Comment: You need a unique constraint on both columns `unique(address, public_key)`

Comment: @klin That's not the same thing. That would allow for a a duplicate `address` as long as its combination with `public_key` is unique. OP's current setup doesn't allow that. If you add the `UNIQUE (address, public_key)` on top of what's already here, it won't fire on the current `UNIQUE (address)` or `UNIQUE (public_key)`, leaving the conflict unresolved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL Upsert With Multiple Constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75451951/postgresql-upsert-with-multiple-constraints). If you need to handle more than one conflict scenario, it has to be done "manually", by first spotting conflicts in your incoming data, then filtering them out prior to the insert.

Comment: @Zegarek - *If you add the UNIQUE (address, public_key) on top of what's already here...* - I didn't recommend this. It's obvious that the current structure of the table contradicts what the OP wants to achieve in the conflict target.

Comment: @klin Let me rephrase: if you suggest replacing the two constraints, it'll end up letting in records that haven't been allowed by the current rules. If you suggest setting it up in addition to those two, it won't solve OP's problem. You clarified you didn't mean the latter, but my comment on the former stands. I'm more inclined to suspect OP expected `on conflict (address, public_key)` to handle conflicts on either of the two constraints pointed out in the question rather than made a mistake in the model.  Still, my guess or yours are as good as any, unless OP clarifies that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to unique keys with one column each.
you need one unique key with two columns.

Or alternative the on conflict clause should only mention one column.

```sql
create table ownerTwoKeys(
    name varchar(30),
    address varchar(30),
    public_key varchar(30),
    CONSTRAINT UQ_address UNIQUE (address),
    CONSTRAINT UQ_public_key UNIQUE (public_key)
);


create table ownerOneKey (
    name varchar(30),
    address varchar(30),
    public_key varchar(30),
    CONSTRAINT UQ_address_public_key UNIQUE (address, public_key)
  
);

INSERT INTO ownerTwoKeys (name, address, public_key) 
VALUES 
('name1', 'address4', 'publicKey1'),
('name1', 'address5', 'publicKey2'),
('name1', 'address6', 'publicKey3'),
('name1', 'address7', 'publicKey4'),
('name1', 'address6', 'publicKey5')
ON CONFLICT (address) DO NOTHING;

select * from ownerTwoKeys;



INSERT INTO ownerOneKey (name, address, public_key) 
VALUES 
('name1', 'address4', 'publicKey1'),
('name1', 'address5', 'publicKey2'),
('name1', 'address6', 'publicKey3'),
('name1', 'address7', 'publicKey4'),
('name1', 'address6', 'publicKey4'),
('name2', 'address6', 'publicKey4')
ON CONFLICT (address, public_key) DO NOTHING;

select * from ownerOneKey;
```

[DB fiddle to play with](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/73t4EVrxFCB2Fy7hp1GrMU/0).

Answer (score 0):

The conflict_target can only handle one potential conflict. That means that you have to make a choice between a unique constraint on address or public_key or the combination of these two columns.

You just can't handle multiple constraint violations with the current implementation of the ON CONFLICT clause.

Comment: [Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75698555/5298879)

Answer (score 0):

As already [pointed out by Frank Heikens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75698095/5298879), you can't handle multiple conflict scenarios in one `on conflict` clause.

Luckily, there's [an exception](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT):

> For `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`, it is optional to specify a `conflict_target`; when omitted, conflicts with all usable constraints (and unique indexes) are handled.

So you can just skip the conflict target list: [online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/52cqYyai)

```sql
INSERT INTO public.owner (name, address, public_key) 
VALUES 
('name1', 'address4', 'publicKey1'),
('name1', 'address5', 'publicKey2'),
('name1', 'address6', 'publicKey3')
ON CONFLICT /*no targets specified*/ DO NOTHING;
```

This works **for this particular case** because there are only 3 constraints, 2 of which you wish to handle this way and the remaining 1 is respected by letting the target table generate the unique `id` on its own.

- If you had more constraints and wanted to skip only these two, `on conflict do nothing` would still skip them all instead.
- If you wanted to resolve conflicts in a specific way using `on conflict do update`, you'd have to specify the one single constraint that solution is meant for. To solve more, you'd need to "manually" avoid them, by first spotting conflicts in your incoming data, then filtering them out prior to the insert, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75451951/postgresql-upsert-with-multiple-constraints).